# Trying to repeat the regex breaks the regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.5

I have a working regex that matches ONE of the following lines:

- A punctuation from the following list `[.,!?;]`
- A word that is preceded by the beginning of the string or a space.

Here's the regex in question `([.,!?;] *|(?<= |\A)[\-'’:\w]+)`

What I need it to do however is for it to match 3 instances of this. So, for example, the ideal end result would be something like this.

```
Sample text: "This is a test. Test"

Output
"This" "is" "a"
"is" "a" "test"
"a" "test" "."
"test" "." "Test"
```

I've tried simply adding `{3}` to the end in the hopes of it matching 3 times. This however results in it matching nothing at all or the occasional odd character. The other possibility I've tried is just repeating the whole regex 3 times like so `([.,!?;] *|(?<= |\A)[\-'’:\w]+)([.,!?;] *|(?<= |\A)[\-'’:\w]+)([.,!?;] *|(?<= |\A)[\-'’:\w]+)` which is horrible to look at but I hoped it would work. This had the odd effect of working, but only if at least one of the matches was one of the previously listed punctuation.

Any insights would be appreciated.

I'm using the [new regex module found here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) so that I can have overlapping searches.

Comment: It'd be a lot easier to see where things go wrong if you actually make a short and self-contained example, with *actual* Python code.

Comment: Which regex attempt in particular did you want an example of? The python code surrounding it shouldn't make a difference but I can put it in if you just want context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What is wrong with your approach**

The `([.,!?;] *|(?<= |\A)[\-'’:\w]+)` pattern matches a single "unit" (either a word or a single punctuation from the specified set `[.,!?;]` followed with 0+ spaces. Thus, when you fed this pattern to the `regex.findall`, it only could return just the chunk list `['This', 'is', 'a', 'test', '. ', 'Test']`.

**Solution**

You can use a slightly different approach: match all words, and all chunks that are not words. Here is a demo (note that `C'est` and `AUX-USB` are treated as single "words"):

```
>>> pat = r"((?:[^\w\s'-]+(?=\s|\b)|\b(?<!')\w+(?:['-]\w+)*))\s*((?1))\s*((?1))"
>>> results = regex.findall(pat, text, overlapped = True)
>>> results
[("C'est", 'un', 'test'), ('un', 'test', '....'), ('test', '....', 'aux-usb')]
```

Here, the pattern **has 3 capture groups**, and the second and third one contain the same pattern as in Group 1 (`(?1)` is a subroutine call used in order to avoid repeating the same pattern used in Group 1). Group 2 and Group 3 can be separated with whitespaces (not necessarily, or the punctuation glued to a word would not be matched). Also, note the negative lookbehind `(?<!')` that will ensure that `C'est` is treated as a single entity.

**Explanation**

The pattern details:

- `((?:[^\w\s'-]+(?=\s|\b)|\b(?<!')\w+(?:['-]\w+)*))` - Group 1 matching:

  - `(?:[^\w\s'-]+(?=\s|\b)` - 1+ characters other than `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, whitespace, `'` and `-` immediately followed with a whitespace or a word boundary
  - `|` - or
  - `\b(?<!')\w+(?:['-]\w+)*)` - 1+ word characters not preceded with a `'` (due to `(?<!')`) and preceded with a word boundary (`\b`) and followed with 0+ sequences of `-` or `'` followed with 1+ word characters.
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `((?1))` - Group 2 (same pattern as for Group 1)
- `\s*((?1))` - see above

Comment: This is interesting, I'll have to mess around with this for a bit. It almost works as is but cuts off hyphenated and contracted words like "we're" or "X-ray".

Comment: This does what I needed, so thanks! I'd be interested to know why `([.,!?;] *|(?<= |\A)[\-'’:\w]+){3}` doesn't work though.

Comment: I will add the explanations now.